# Typed Dataset designer, I need to fill multiple tables with a single database call where the stored procedure returns multiple resultsets

Tags: c#, visual-studio, strongly-typed-dataset, sqldataadapter, dataset-designer

It is possible to achieve the following:
On the Dataset designer, I create three tables and then with a single data adapter call a stored procedure that returns three result sets that I need to fill into these three tables.

I have tried the following:
On the designer created three data tables.
[image]

Here is the code that I am writing:

```
PaymentDomainData paymentDomain = new PaymentDomainData();
SqlDataAdapter adapter = Helper.GetAdapter(StoredProcedureConstant.PAYMENT_DOMAIN_SELECT);
                adapter.TableMappings.Add(sourceTable: DataTableConstant.TABLE, 
                    dataSetTable: DataTableConstant.PAYMENT_MODE);
                adapter.TableMappings.Add(sourceTable: DataTableConstant.TABLE_1,
                    dataSetTable: DataTableConstant.PAYMENT_STATUS);
                adapter.TableMappings.Add(sourceTable: DataTableConstant.TABLE_2,
                    dataSetTable: DataTableConstant.PAYMENT_MODE_PAYMENT_STATUS);

adapter.Fill(paymentDomain);
```

The tables all turn out to be empty. I have test the stored procedure to ensure that it does return data when invoked directly from the management studio.

Thanks in advance for looking up my question.